# Opacity effecting absolutely positioned element

Tags: html, element, opacity, absolute

I have two containers (container1 and container2) and in container1 I have a child element. This child element is absolutely positioned and half the element overlaps over container2. I understand if I add opacity to container1 all it's child elements inherent the property but if I add opacity to container2 it ends up effecting the child element of container1 even though container2 is not it's parent element. An explanation would be very helpful.

#### Here is the HTML code:

```
  <body>
    <div id="container1" style='height: 250px; background-color: red'>
      <div id="child" style="height: 290px; width: 200px; background-color: green; position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 30%"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="container2" style="height: 250px; background-color: purple; font-size: 130px; opacity: 0.5">Some really big text</div>
  </body>
```

Here is a screenshot of what's happening: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A84Li.png

Answer (score 1):

I think it is due to the green element being behind the purple element. Essentially, the purple `<div>` element is casting a purple tint over the green child `<div>`. When the opacity of `container2` is set to anything other than, `opacity:1` it seems to be causing `child` to be overlaid by `container2`. In this case setting the `z-index` will resolve the issue. Where the `z-index` will control the hierarchy outwards perpendicular to the xy-plane. Press the <kbd>Run code snippet</kbd> button below to see the results:

```css
#container1 {
  height: 250px;
  background-color: red
}

#child {
  height: 290px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 30%;
  z-index: 1;
}

#container2 {
  height: 250px;
  background-color: purple;
  font-size: 130px;
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container1">
    <div id="child"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="container2"></div>

</body>
```